# Is there any way to generically search for relations between (transparent) Tables?

Tags: foreign-key-relationship, abap, relation

I'm looking for a way to get from table A to table B via foreign key relationships.

Say for instance (and this is just a watered down example), I'd like to know how the tables `AFPO` and `VEKP` are related.

Looking at the definitions of those tables I can see that they can be related like this (not including all of the the details):

```
AFPO~AUFNR = AUFK~AUFNR
AUFK~AUFNR = LIKP~TERNR
LIKP~TERNR = VEKO~VBELN
VEKO~VENUM = VEKP~VENUM
```

Of course there could be a lot more ways in which one could define a relation between these 2 tables in a meaningful way (for instance only including master data and transactional data. This is to exclude relations like MARA -> T000 -> SOOD ).

So does anyone know a generic way to do this? Like a report / transaction / function module...?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function module, which supplies you with all information of a table. It is called "DDIF_TABL_GET".
You can recieve several tables with all settings and attributes of your requested table. For example you can recieve the table DD05M and there are some fields called "FORTABLE", which gives you the name of the foreign key field table and the field "FORKEY" which contains the name of the foreign key of your requested table. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: thx for the answer. I was aware of all of those development objects, and i'm on my way of using them in order to create my custom program. Sorry if i've missed a few details with my questions, what I was looking for was a way to establish a relation between tables that are not linked in table DD05L, but are linked thorugh a series of tables which are defined in DD05L as linked. Ex AFPO -> AUFK -> LIKP -> VEKO -> VEKP. Anyway, i'm almost done with that. I may publish the code if it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the short answer to this question is, "Welcome to ERP development."

If there is a relationship between two tables, their fields *should* refer to the appropriate fields in the master/header tables via foreign keys (check tables in SAP).  Unfortunately, this doesn't always happen, or can't happen due to semantic reasons.

SAP anticipated this and provided the data dictionary - one of the most underestimated strengths of the SAP development environment. The reusable data elements and domains provide a good way to see the semantic and syntactic correlations between data.

Link: [Data Element, Domain, and the Way They Interact](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/60aa1742-0ef2-2c10-1592-84e1f99ad34e?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&46493021596920)

So if the foreign key field is not defined, your next best bet is to do a where-used search on the data element.

Comment: I already implemented something like what i was asking for. If foreign keys or at least check tables are not defined, i can't guarantee anything with it, but it does manage to find all the relations i know are possible (and some dumber solutions also).